# error in connecting BIRT with SQLServer 2014 Enterprise

Tags: sql-server, eclipse, connection, birt

This error revealed when am taring to connect BIRT with sql server 2014 enterprise. Can any one help?

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: There is an error in get connection, Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:64567f1f-987e-485c-af02-204e770945ae.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.doConnect(JDBCDriverManager.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.getConnection(JDBCDriverManager.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.tryCreateConnection(JDBCDriverManager.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.testConnection(JDBCDriverManager.java:748)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.util.DriverLoader.testConnection(DriverLoader.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.util.DriverLoader.testConnection(DriverLoader.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.profile.JDBCSelectionPageHelper.testConnection(JDBCSelectionPageHelper.java:998)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.profile.JDBCSelectionPageHelper.access$11(JDBCSelectionPageHelper.java:960)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.profile.JDBCSelectionPageHelper$8.widgetSelected(JDBCSelectionPageHelper.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.actions.NewDataSourceAction.run(NewDataSourceAction.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.rcp.DesignerApplication.run(DesignerApplication.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
```

Comment: You need to post some code for us to look at your problem

Comment: I second that, without code it is hard to offer any assistance.

Comment: no not code when i'am  trying to create now data source on BIRT eclipse ,  i put the driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (v4.0) . and the url : jdbc:sqlserver://MH-PC\PCMH  ; databaseName = App but that error message appeared